# mysq_query doesn't work with NOW()

Tags: php, mysql

For some reason this function stopped working:

```
mysql_query("DELETE FROM `x_servers` WHERE `end_date` <= NOW() AND `service_type` = 'timeboost' OR `end_date` <= NOW() AND `service_type` = 'vip'") or die(mysql_error());
```

Notably it worked fine before, so I suspect this happened after moving to mysql 5.7

Thing is that the function works if I remove the `end_date` <= NOW()` clause, so I think there's a problem with NOW().

Tried looking around and tried replacing it with CURDATE() and other synonyms but nothing worked. Hope that somebody can help.

Comment: What's the error that you are getting?

Comment: Forgot to enable errors. Thank you! It says:
PHP Deprecated:  mysql_connect(): The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead in /var/www/cron.php on line 11

Actually no. it's another line. so I suppose it doesn't give any error.

Comment: Hi! If you try to use it in a select statement instead, (`SELECT * FROM `x_servers` WHERE `end_date` <= NOW() AND `service_type` = 'timeboost' OR `end_date` <= NOW() AND `service_type` = 'vip'`) do you get any results? And what if you only try `SELECT NOW()` - does that produce a valid date?

Comment: SELECT NOW() produces a date

Comment: The command you gave produced zero results...

Comment: ohh snap. Sorry. The date was wrong. my bad.

Comment: Thanks MacPrawn, and everyone else. :)

Comment: Please make note of the ***big red warning*** on the [doc page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) and stop using `mysql_*`.